# Ruby loop through and print out available methods/attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I list out all the attributes or methods available for the provider below?

Other scripts make use of providers method/attribute like below:

```
if provider
  provider.miq_templates.each do |template|
  ....

if provider
  provider.security_groups.each do |security_group|
  ....
```

So I want to print out everything it has like `miq_templates`, `security_groups` etc.,

I tried the following:

```
if provider
  log(:info, "provider is : #{provider.methods}")
end
```

`Output:`

```
provider is : [:hash, :==, :method_missing, :__drbref, :pretty_print_cycle, :pretty_print, :__drburi, :eql?, :respond_to?, :_dump, :to_json, :with_options, :blank?, :as_json, :duplicable?, :deep_dup, :in?, :presence_in, :present?, :presence, :to_yaml, :acts_like?, :html_safe?, :instance_variable_names, :instance_values, :to_param, :to_query, :try!, :try, :instance_variable_defined?, :remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :instance_variable_set, :protected_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :private_methods, :public_methods, :public_send, :method, :public_method, :singleton_method, :class_eval, :define_singleton_method, :extend, :to_enum, :enum_for, :<=>, :===, :=~, :!~, :freeze, :object_id, :send, :nil?, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :itself, :yield_self, :then, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods, :equal?, :!, :instance_exec, :!=, :instance_eval, :__id__, :__send__]
```

If I try the following:

```
if provider
  log(:info, "provider is : #{provider.public_method}")
end
```

Then I get the following error:

```
`public_method': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
```

Any example on how to print out public_methods or any other in the list?

Here is the code

```
def get_provider(provider_id=nil)
  $evm.root.attributes.detect { |k,v| provider_id = v if k.end_with?('provider_id') } rescue nil
  provider = $evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Amazon_CloudManager).find_by_id(provider_id)
  log(:info, "Found provider: #{provider.name} via provider_id: #{provider.id}") if provider

  if !provider
    provider = $evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Amazon_CloudManager).first
    if provider
      log(:info, "Found provider: #{provider.name} via default method")
    else
      bail_out('< No providers found, check RBAC tags >')
    end
  end
  provider ? (return provider) : (return nil)
end


provider = get_provider(query_catalogitem(:src_ems_id)) || get_provider_from_template()


if provider
  log(:info, "provider is : #{provider}")
end

if provider
  provider.miq_templates.each do |template|
    log(:info, "miq_templates is : #{template.id}")
    next if template.archived || template.orphaned  
    #dialog_hash[template.guid] = "#{template.name} on #{provider.name}"
    dialog_hash[template.id] = "#{template.name} on #{provider.name}"
  end
else
  # no provider so list everything
  $evm.vmdb(:ManageIQ_Providers_Amazon_CloudManager_Template).all.each do |template|
    next if template.archived || template.orphaned
     #dialog_hash[template[:guid]] = "#{template.name} on #{template.ext_management_system.name}"
      dialog_hash[template[:id]] = "#{template.name} on #{template.ext_management_system.name}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what your code's supposed to do at a high level, but

> How can I list out all the attributes or methods available for the provider below?

What you're looking for is probably the [#public_methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Object.html#method-i-public_methods) method defined for all Ruby objects. It returns an array of symbols each representing a public method; to then call it use `object.public_send(:method_name)`. If the method takes arguments, just add them to [#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Object.html#method-i-public_send) arguments; e. g.:

`5.public_send(:+, 7)` is equivalent to `5.+(7)` or `5 + 7`

The array returned doesn't allow you to see whether the method takes arguments or not, refer to the documentation of whatever you're using or dig deeper into [the Method class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Method.html)

You call also use `#private_methods` and `#send` instead of `#public_methods` and `#public_send`, this will allow you to "break into" the object, but generally sticking to `public` is a better idea and tends to break less things.

Comment: I want to find out what all things `provider` has? Based on other scripts it has `miq_templates, security_groups` but there are more and I want to print that out for the `provider` so I can get a list and make use of it

Comment: `miq_templates, security_groups` aren't public methods. I tried to print `provider.methods` and it doesn't include `miq_templates, security_groups`. So it must be something else

Comment: Maybe I need to print out or dump `:_dump, :to_json,` using this. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: According to the list you showed, `provider` responds to `method_missing`. `method_missing`, as the name implies, is a method that allows an object to handle missing methods. `provider`, therefore, can respond to *any method whatsoever* by handling it in `method_missing`. Only the source code of `method_missing`, the documentation of `provider`'s class, or the author of that class can tell you.